# C# SharpPcap issues

Tags: c#, tcp, sharppcap

I've been very interested in using [SharpPcap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sharppcap/), but so far it's not been going well.

The main problem is the following code:

```
   private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs packet)
   {
        if(packet is TCPPacket)
        {                
            DateTime time = packet.Timeval.Date;
            int len = packet.PcapHeader.len;

            TCPPacket tcp = (TCPPacket)packet;
            string srcIp = tcp.SourceAddress;
            string dstIp = tcp.DestinationAddress;
            int srcPort = tcp.SourcePort;
            int dstPort = tcp.DestinationPort;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2},
                {3} Len={4} {5}:{6} -> {7}:{8}", 
                time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second, 
                time.Millisecond, len, srcIp, srcPort, 
                dstIp, dstPort);
        }
    }
```

> "The type or namespace TCPPacket could
>   not be found"

OK, so I figured it must be TcpPacket? -but then it came up with this error:

> "The given expression is never of the
>   provided ('PacketDotNet.TcpPacket')
>   type"

Ignoring that:

> "'SharpPcap.CaptureEventArgs' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Timeval' and
>   no extension method 'Timeval'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'SharpPcap.CaptureEventArgs' could be
>   found"

And so on, and so on. So my question is, am I missing something?

I have the PacketDotNet and SharpPcap library's, and added both the using statements.

Solution:
        Packet pack = Packet.ParsePacket(packet.Packet);
        TcpPacket tcpPacket = TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(pack);

```
    DateTime time = packet.Packet.Timeval.Date;
    int len = packet.Packet.Data.Length;

    if (tcpPacket != null)
    {
        IpPacket ipPacket = (IpPacket)tcpPacket.ParentPacket;


            IPAddress srcIp = ipPacket.SourceAddress;
            IPAddress dstIp = ipPacket.DestinationAddress;
            ushort srcPort = tcpPacket.SourcePort;
            ushort dstPort = tcpPacket.DestinationPort;

            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2},{3} Len={4} {5}:{6} -> {7}:{8}",
                                time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second, time.Millisecond, len,
                                srcIp, srcPort, dstIp, dstPort)
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

```
Packet pack = Packet.ParsePacket(packet.Packet);
TcpPacket tcpPacket = TcpPacket.GetEncapsulated(pack);

DateTime time = packet.Packet.Timeval.Date;
int len = packet.Packet.Data.Length;

if (tcpPacket != null)
{
    IpPacket ipPacket = (IpPacket)tcpPacket.ParentPacket;


        IPAddress srcIp = ipPacket.SourceAddress;
        IPAddress dstIp = ipPacket.DestinationAddress;
        ushort srcPort = tcpPacket.SourcePort;
        ushort dstPort = tcpPacket.DestinationPort;

        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}:{1}:{2},{3} Len={4} {5}:{6} -> {7}:{8}",
                            time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second, time.Millisecond, len,
                            srcIp, srcPort, dstIp, dstPort)
            );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the first part of the code...

```
private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs packet)
   {
        if(packet is TCPPacket)
        {
```

packet seems to be of type CaptureEventArgs, not TCPPacket.  Probably there's some property of the event args which is your actual packet.  If that is correct, then the

> "'SharpPcap.CaptureEventArgs' does not
>   contain a definition for 'Timeval' and
>   no extension method 'Timeval'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'SharpPcap.CaptureEventArgs' could be
>   found"

Is probably true for that reason;  the CaptureEventArgs and the Packet are not the same thing.

**EDIT:**

I would try something like:

```
private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs packet)
   {
        if(packet.packet is TCPPacket)
        {               
            TCPPacket tcpPack = (TCPPacket)(packet.packet);
            DateTime time = tcpPack.Timeval.Date;
            int len = tcpPack.PcapHeader.len;           
            string srcIp = tcpPack.SourceAddress;
            string dstIp = tcpPack.DestinationAddress;
            int srcPort = tcpPack.SourcePort;
            int dstPort = tcpPack.DestinationPort;

            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}:{2},
                {3} Len={4} {5}:{6} -> {7}:{8}", 
                time.Hour, time.Minute, time.Second, 
                time.Millisecond, len, srcIp, srcPort, 
                dstIp, dstPort);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ooh right, I forgot to mention that I tried packet.Packet, which seems to be the actual packet. But that didn't change anything.

Comment: as in, everywhere where you have the word packet (except the function header) you have the words "packet.packet"?

Comment: Yes:
            if(packet.Packet == TcpPacket)
            {
                DateTime time = packet.Packet.Timeval.Date;
                int len = packet.Packet.PcapHeader.len;
 
                TcpPacket tcp = (TcpPacket)packet.Packet;

Comment: See my edit;  I would be surprised if you still encountered the "Does not contain a definition" error, at least.  If you still have errors, it'd be helpful if you would indicate which line the error is originating from.

Comment: Sorry, it's really still the same. I'll update my first post.

Comment: Do you have the "using PacketDotNet;" statement in your headers?  If so, the casing of TCPPacket could be off;  C# being case-sensitive, it could easily be TcpPacket.

Comment: Isn't that what I have now? -that's the first thing I tried. Ooh, by the way, thank you for the help so far!

Comment: Try using the object browser in visual studio to look inside the PacketDotNet library;  what's happening here is that you are using "TcpPacket", and the compiler doesn't know where to find it.  So we are either missing a "Reference" to the PacketDotNet library, a "using" statement for the PacketDotNet library, or we're using the wrong class IN the PacketDotNet library.

Comment: I figured it out. *sigh* I'll edit my first post, thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: No problem, that's what these sites are for.  If you have the exact problem figured out, you ought to post it as an answer and mark it as 'accepted';  that will make it easier for future users with the same problem to rapidly identify the solution.